# Moving a widget inside a layout C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget, qml

I am having trouble moving a widget inside another widget:

[image]

It may be simple but I just can't get it:

- My main widget is in a `QHBoxlayout`
- My child widget is within the main widget’s layout (the tumbler highlighted in yellow in the pic) which I need to relocate
- I need to move the child widget `quickWidgettum` which is just the tumbler within the parent widget.
- The parent widget `mstrWnd` is everything else on screen.

Here the C++ code:

```
mstrWnd = new QWidget;                                                      
        mstrWnd->setObjectName(STR_MASTER_WINDOW_NAME);                                 
mstrWnd->setWindowTitle(getSettingI(MSTR_APP_TITLE));                       
        mstrWnd->setGeometry(getSettingI(MSTR_APP_X).toInt(),                       
            getSettingI(MSTR_APP_Y).toInt(),                                        
            getSettingI(MSTR_APP_WIDTH).toInt(),                                    
            getSettingI(MSTR_APP_HEIGHT).toInt());                                  
        mstrWnd->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Window);
        mstrWnd->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);

        QHBoxLayout* laos = new QHBoxLayout();
        mstrWnd->setLayout(laos);

        QQuickView* quickView = new QQuickView(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir::currentPath() + "\\Resources\\videos\\aos.qml"));
quickView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
quickWidgettum = new QWidget;
        quickWidgettum = QWidget::createWindowContainer(quickView);

        laos->addWidget(quickWidgettum);
```

And here the QML part:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Rectangle {
    width: frame.implicitWidth + 10
    height: frame.implicitHeight + 10

    function formatText(count, modelData) {
        var data = count === 12 ? modelData + 1 : modelData;
        return data.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + data : data;
    }

    FontMetrics {
        id: fontMetrics
    }

    Component {
        id: delegateComponent

        Label {
            text: formatText(Tumbler.tumbler.count, modelData)
            opacity: 1.0 - Math.abs(Tumbler.displacement) / (Tumbler.tumbler.visibleItemCount / 2)
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pixelSize: fontMetrics.font.pixelSize * 1.25
        }
    }

    Frame {
        id: frame
        padding: 0
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Row {
            id: row

            Tumbler {
                id: hoursTumbler
                model: 12
                delegate: delegateComponent
            }

            Tumbler {
                id: minutesTumbler
                model: 60
                delegate: delegateComponent
            }

            Tumbler {
                id: amPmTumbler
                model: ["AM", "PM"]
                delegate: delegateComponent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This line was affecting the position of the widget  anchors.centerIn: parent

Removing it from the QML file fixed my issue